# ERROR 1055: grouping distinct columns and sum of another column - SQL

Tags: sql, sum

Have a table that contains artists and sales (there are multiple of the same artist and songs they created) I cant seem to get the sum of sales fro distinct artists to come out.

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT(artist, sales), SUM(sales) 
-> FROM songs
-> GROUP BY sales;
```

Sample OutPut
Distinct Artist 1 - total sales
Distinct Artist 2 - total sale
Distinct Artist 3 - total sales

Comment: Please add sample input/output data to your question to help explain what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

> get the sum of sales from distinct artists

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select artist, sum(sales) total_sales from songs group by artist
```